# How does VBA/VB6 layout the memory of a class that implements several interfaces?

Tags: vba, class, pointers, vb6, memory-layout

I'm exploring the layout of fields and pointers for a class instance, in VBA. I assume that the layout is similar if not the same for VB6. I've been able to use various bits and pieces from this [VBForums thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?781595-VB6-Call-Functions-By-Pointer-(Universall-DLL-Calls)) to help find the public and private members of the class, but I'm unsure how to determine which interfaces are implemented by the class, how that's laid out in memory, and how to find the pointers for the interface members.

How can I discover as much as possible about the layout of the class?

Aside from VB functions like `ObjPtr`, `VarPtr` and `StrPtr`, a little bit of memory arithmetic and Win32 function `CopyMemory`, are there any programming methods for helping to determine the layout?

Comment: [This old blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040205-00/?p=40733) should give you some useful information about the layout.

Comment: [Updated link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040205-00/?p=40733) RE: BobRodes